# Null Pointer Exception on starting spring web application after migrating spring and hibernate to the latest version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I migrated a web project which used spring 4.1.2 and hibernate 4.3.11 to the latest versions ( spring - 5.3.6, hibernate - 6.0.0Alpha7 ). When starting the application in tomcat, I encountered a Null Pointer Exception.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0' of type [org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#1' of type [org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'mainDataSource' of type [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer (file:/G:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CalERP/WEB-INF/lib/guava-15.0.jar) to field java.lang.Thread.inheritableThreadLocals
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'dataSource' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'jdbcRealm' of type [org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'securityManager' of type [org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor#0' of type [org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
WARN : org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass - HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.cal.common.dataaccesslayer.model.AlertActionPK
WARN : org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass - HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.cal.common.dataaccesslayer.model.AlertActionPK
WARN : com.cal.erp.accounts.views.AllowRawInjectionDespiteWrappingXMLWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'syncableEntityDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-CalERP.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'syncableEntityDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-CalERP.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-CalERP.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlExpressionResolver.createColumnReferenceKey(SqlExpressionResolver.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ordering.ast.ColumnReference.apply(ColumnReference.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ordering.OrderByFragmentImpl.apply(OrderByFragmentImpl.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$generateSelect$1(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:451)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.generateSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.createSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4586)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4578)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 56 more
```

I have debugged and find out the null pointer exception happens when `tableGroup.getTableReferenceJoins()`is empty in the method getTableReference in org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ordering.ast.ColumnReference class.

```
TableReference getTableReference(TableGroup tableGroup) {
        ModelPartContainer modelPart = tableGroup.getModelPart();
        if ( modelPart instanceof PluralAttributeMapping ) {
            MappingType partMappingType = ( (PluralAttributeMapping) modelPart ).getElementDescriptor()
                    .getPartMappingType();
            if ( partMappingType instanceof AbstractEntityPersister ) {
                AbstractEntityPersister abstractEntityPersister = (AbstractEntityPersister) partMappingType;
                int i = abstractEntityPersister.determineTableNumberForColumn( columnExpression );
                String tableName = abstractEntityPersister.getTableName( i );
                for ( TableReferenceJoin tableReferenceJoin : tableGroup.getTableReferenceJoins() ) {
                    final TableReference joinedTableReference = tableReferenceJoin.getJoinedTableReference();
                    if ( joinedTableReference.getTableExpression()
                            .equals( tableName ) ) {
                        return joinedTableReference;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return tableGroup.getPrimaryTableReference();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

On further debugging, I found out that a one-many relationship for the field `accountingTransactionJournalItems` specified in `AccountingTransactionJournal` entity classes is causing this issue. That suspected entity classes are given below.

**AccountingTransactionJournal.java**

```
package com.cal.common.accounts.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;

import com.cal.common.accounts.enums.AccountingTransactionJournalType;
import com.cal.core.foundation.model.BaseEntity;

@Entity
@Table(name="accounting_transaction_journal")
public class AccountingTransactionJournal {

    private Long accountingJournalId;
    private Set<AccountingTransactionJournalItem> accountingTransactionJournalItems=new HashSet<AccountingTransactionJournalItem>(0);
    //other fields
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="acc_journal_id")
    public Long getAccountingJournalId() {
        return accountingJournalId;
    }
    public void setAccountingJournalId(Long accountingJournalId) {
        this.accountingJournalId = accountingJournalId;
    }
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="accountingTransactionJournal", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy
    @BatchSize(size=1024)
    public Set<AccountingTransactionJournalItem> getAccountingTransactionJournalItems() {
        return accountingTransactionJournalItems;
    }
    public void setAccountingTransactionJournalItems(
            Set<AccountingTransactionJournalItem> accountingTransactionJournalItems) {
        this.accountingTransactionJournalItems = accountingTransactionJournalItems;
        
    }
    
}
```

**AccountingTransactionJournalItem.java**

```
package com.cal.common.accounts.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.cal.core.foundation.model.BaseEntity;

@Entity
@Table(name="accounting_transaction_journal_item")
public class AccountingTransactionJournalItem {

    private Long accountingJournalItemId;
    private AccountingTransactionJournal accountingTransactionJournal;
    //other fields
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="acc_journal_item_id")
    public Long getAccountingJournalItemId() {
        return accountingJournalItemId;
    }
    public void setAccountingJournalItemId(Long accountingJournalItemId) {
        this.accountingJournalItemId = accountingJournalItemId;
    }
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="acc_transaction_journal_id")
    public AccountingTransactionJournal getAccountingTransactionJournal() {
        return accountingTransactionJournal;
    }
    public void setAccountingTransactionJournal(AccountingTransactionJournal accountingTransactionJournal) {
        this.accountingTransactionJournal = accountingTransactionJournal;
    }
    
    
}
```

**applicationContext-CalERP.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Enable @Service and @Autowired annotations -->

    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cal" />
    
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:jdbc.properties,classpath:mail.properties,classpath:product_en.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
        
        
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:message</value>
            <value>classpath:mail</value>
            <value>classpath:auditlog</value>
            <value>classpath:product_en</value>
            <value>classpath:query_en</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"></property>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="mainDataSource">
        </property>
    </bean>
    
      <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="read*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut" expression="execution(* com.*.service.*Service.*(..))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="userDaoPointCut" expression="execution(* com.*.dao.*Dao.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userDaoPointCut" />
    </aop:config>
       
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
    

    <!-- BoneCP configuration -->
    <bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60" />
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="90" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="60" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="20" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="3" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="10" />
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="50" />
        <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="select 1" />
        <property name="maxConnectionAgeInSeconds" value="0" />
        <!-- <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="hibernateNaming" class="com.cal.common.hibernate.CustomNamingStrategy"></bean> -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <!-- <property name="namingStrategy" ref="hibernateNaming"></property> -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.cal.common.dataaccesslayer.model</value>
                <value>com.cal.common.accounts.model</value>
                <value>com.cal.core.foundation.model</value>
                <value>com.cal.common.erp.worksheet.model</value>
                <value>com.cal.emc.model</value>
                <value>com.cal.report.style</value>
                <value>com.cal.report.templates</value>
                <value>com.cal.rma.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
                </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Mail Service -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mail.hostname}"></property>
        <property name="port" value="${mail.portno}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${mail.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"></property>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
                <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mailService" class="com.cal.common.service.impl.MailServiceImpl">
        <property name="siteUrl">
            <value>${mail.application.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"></property>
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Mail Service Ends-->
    
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Does any one knows what's the problem in this one-many relationship ?

Comment: why do you have a `@OrderBy` on a method that returns a `Set`?

Comment: also, `@BatchSize` is meant to be used with lazy loading...

Comment: Forgot to remove it since it hasn't caused any issues till now.

Comment: is also probably relevant the file `/WEB-INF/applicationContext-CalERP.xml`

Comment: added /WEB-INF/applicationContext-CalERP.xml

Comment: Hibernate 6 isn't supported, the latest 5.4.x is the supported version.